# When I filter I need to request.GET.value to be selected

Tags: html, django, forms, django-templates

I have to filter some data so I need to use a select field but when I submit the form the result disappears. I have to selected the value that is choice previous

```
` <label class="text-secondary">Discount Type</label>
  <select  name="discount_type" class="form-control" >
    <option  value="" class="text-center" >Select Type</option>
    {% for i in type %}
      <option {% if i.0 == request.GET.status %} selected {% endif %} 
       value="{{ i.0   }}" >{{ i.1 }}
      </option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>`
```

Comment: Please provide further code for the form element, it may be that you are submitting the form to early or causing the form to reset during the submissions phase.

Comment: <div class="col-md-2">
           <label class="text-secondary">Search & Filter</label> <br/>
           <button class="btn btn-block btn-secondary">Filter</button>
    </div>

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to create a variable in the context?
Here the problem is during the POST you probably don't have the request.GET values anymore

This could be helpful

[Django : Maintaining option selected in HTML template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575518/django-maintaining-option-selected-in-html-template)